# Can we derive the distribution of a random variable based on a dependent random variable's distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, probability-distribution, statistical-ai, bayesian-networks

In the diagram below, there are three variables: `X3` is a function of (depends on) `X1` and `X2`, `X2` also depends on `X1`. More specifically, `X3 = f(X1, x2)` and `X2 = g(X1)`. Therefore, `X3 = f(X1, g(X1))`.

[image]

If the probabilistic distribution of `X1` is known, is it possible to derive the probabilistic distribution of `X3`?

Comment: I don't think you can know the probability distribution of $X_3$ without knowing the functions $f$ and $g$, which define how $X_3$ is dependent on $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, provided you know about $f$ and $g$. Expression $X3 = f(X1, g(X1))$can be written as $X3 = h(X1)$ where $h$ takes into account both $f$ and $g$. After this finding the PDF is simple by differentiating the CDF:
$$ F_{X3} (x3) = P(X3 \leq x3) =  P(h(X1) \leq x3) = P(X1 \leq h^{-1}(x3))$$

$$ \frac {d F_{X3} (x3)}{dx3}  = \frac {d P(X1 \leq h^{-1}(x3))}{dx3} = f_{X3}(x3)$$

NOTE: The conventions followed are the same as used in the field of Probablity

(Take care of the function inversion step in non-monotonic cases)

Check these [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-AzW70e2M0&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60hI9ATjSFgLZpbNJ7myAg6&index=115).

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. We could derive the most probable $x_3$ by calculating the maximum likelihood: $x^*_3=\underset{x_3}{\arg\max} p(x_1,x_2|x_3)$. We are unable to calculate this as you only stated that there is a correlation, but we don't know how it looks like.